# Copy whole column content into array (Power Automate)

Tags: list, flow, sharepoint-list, power-automate

I want to bring every value of a SharePoint List column to an array.

At the moment I'm using an 'Apply to each' connector to iterate the whole column and then use the 'Add to Array' connector to fill the array.

[image]

Is there a command/connector to directly copy the whole column content to the array?

Comment: What do you mean by **Whole Column**?  Power Automate's **[Get items]** action retrieves all items based on the Filter and put it into an array/collection. And you're already using that in your flow as you've added **[Apply to each]**. Please provide example what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: At the moment my Testflow needs about 2:30 minutes to loop through a filtered list with 400 items to add each value of the column 'Ressort' to the array using the **Apply to each** method. If the list is longer it takes even more time for a in my opinion simple process.
My idea was if there's something like a _Set Array = Filtered column_ or so, so I can avoid the timeconsuming iteration process. Back in Excel VBA I could set an array variable equal to a column range and instantly got the finished variable and didn't have to go through each cell and write the value into the variable like Flow

Comment: I think we can do that.. let me verify that and post my response

Comment: Just posted my response. Let me know if you're looking for this or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly populate an array variable by using **[Select]** and **[Set variable]** actions as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Perfect!